# Run method at application start

Tags: c#, timer

I'd like to draw X and Y axes on a panel at application launch.
I've created this method:

```
    public void Draw_axes()  
    {
    Graphics gs = panel_main.CreateGraphics();
    gs.DrawLine(pen, panel_main.Width / 2, 0, panel_main.Width / 2,     (panel_main.Height ));  //Asse Y
         gs.DrawLine(pen, 0, panel_main.Height /2, panel_main.Width, panel_main.Height / 2);  // Asse X
     }
```

I tried to insert it in a Load but it doesn't work.
I tried with the timer (I don't know how to use it very well though) but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean you tried it in a `Load`?

Comment: Drawing anything on the form is going to get wiped out every time the form is repainted (which happens a lot). you need to put this in the paint event.

Comment: What's the exact code I shoud write? I'm very new in C# programming. Thanks

Comment: Calling `CreateGraphics` like that will not work properly.  As soon as the PictureBox is repainted, you will lose what you drew.  Instead, handle the `Paint` event of the `PictureBox` and draw you axes there and anything else that needs drawing.

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to draw the axes correctly